# Can I creat a website using only php? if not why?

Tags: php, html, web

I'm trying to create a website, and this my first time. I know HTML, and some CSS.
But I'm not really sure do I need html pages or just keep all of them php.

Thank you

Comment: You can write all your HTML contents inside a PHP page, but that should not be the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the php echo function to output all HTML that is needed for your website but I don't think that is what you are looking for. As AlphaDelta said your users would not see anything when visiting your website. I would not recommend you echoing your entire html code for multiple reasons:

1.) it would be very hard to find errors especially since there are now more possibilitys for making errors

2.) the reasons why we have html, css, js, php, etc. is to seperate the tasks to provide the content and interactivity of your website to dedicated processes (as others allready pointed out)

3.) you would not gain any advantage, the echoed code can still be seen by the client so if you are looking for a way to hide your code this is not it

Answer (score 0):

PHP is an HTML preprocessor, all it does is process things before sending users HTML; you certainly could make an entire website in PHP but the user won't see anything because you wouldn't be sending them any HTML to render a page.

HTML is a markup language necessary for users to draw and view pages.

Answer (score 0):

Under website I understand 2 parts (this is **extremely simplified**):

1. What user will see - html, css, js (front-end);
2. Back-end - let's name it what server is processing, storing etc.

So if you will not use HTML, CSS - user **will be unable** to perform even basic interaction with your website.